# download WineBottler with AdBlocker (Privoxy and Adblock Edge)

Tags: software-recommendation, data-transfer, software, wine

Because of security (malware) I run two ad blockers. System wide proxy `Privoxy` and browser plugin `Adblock Edge`.

I wish to download [WineBottler 1.8-rc4 Development](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/)

[image]

and I received this strange error (all other sites work)

[image]

after I disabled Privoxy temporal in browser network settings

[image]

still issues. Is there a mirror? Howto download without getting security trouble?

Comment: Temporary de-configure your proxy. When a proxy server is off, and OS X is still configured to use it, then it will show a can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adf.ly is basically an Ad page which will show the real link after some seconds. That's the direct link for the file you are looking for:

http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/combo/builds/WineBottlerCombo_1.8-rc4.dmg

Comment: I pressed the download button there and was lead to the page http://clearload.bid/-36721EUDK/CF9L?rndad=2605e00021d13f00a5a5f4f8f300bbe8-1534107142. I waited for 5 seconds and pressed the Skip Ad button as directed and was transferred here
 https://clearload.bid/not-found.php. What would be the remedy?